# How to create PendingServiceRouting for External Routing using rest API

Tags: omnichannel

I am trying to create a PendingServiceRouting object for external routing using Postman, however it just gives me the following error:

```
{
        "message": "field integrity exception",
        "errorCode": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
        "fields": []
}
```

Following are the details I am sending in the body

```
https://ap8.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/PendingServiceRouting

{
    "CapacityWeight": 1,
    "IsReadyForRouting": "true",
    "RoutingModel": "ExternalRouting",
    "RoutingPriority": 1,
    "ServiceChannelId": "0N90o000000kK6nCAE",
    "WorkItemId": "5000o00002N7doWAAR",
    "RoutingType": "QueueBased"
}
```

Can someone point out if there is some setting or value being missed? Omni-channel is enabled and **MostAvailable** with **SkillBased** routing is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Queue-based PendingServiceRouting creation is not supported. We have a bug logged for the same according to which,the error message needs to be more clear explaining that a QueueBased PSR creation is not supported. I have followed up with our team for more inputs and will update this thread as I hear back.

The fact that the Apex code snippet in the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_skills_based_routing_define_apex_action_class.htm&type=5) is explicitly provided for skill-based routing implicitly means queue-based routing is not supported, as a similar example would be showing for it, if it was supported. Recommend logging this as an Idea on [Salesforce IdeaExchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideasearch)

It is also worth noting that as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/omnichannel_external_routing_expected_behavior.htm),

> We don’t recommend using both external routing and Omni-Channel queue-based routing in the same implementation. If the same agent is in both queues, the agent’s capacity could be exceeded. We don't have control over an agent's capacity in external routing. If you attempt this combination, there can be unknown issues.

Also, Skills-based routing isn’t supported for external routing.
([Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_skills_based_routing_limitations.htm&type=5))

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info. Could you then suggest some way or which could help me create AgentWork object for the SF agent for external routing as the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/omnichannel_external_routing_pushtopic.htm) for External Routing for Omni Channel only states to watch out for PSR with ExternalRouting

Comment: Why not just put an external routing configuration on the queue, and then put the object you’re trying to route into the external queue? This way, the PSR object creation can be automated instead of using code

Comment: Are there any docs for this as i m fairly new to this?